# call server event after javascript function on html button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a javascript function called `SignUp_Client()`and a `SignUp_Server` event in a code-behind page. I want to call the `SignUp_Server` event when `SignUp_Client` returns `true`. But I am unable to call the event though `SignUp_Client()` returns `true`. What am I missing here?

```
<input type="button" id="btnSignUp" runat="server" value="Sign Up" onclick = "return SignUp_Client();" onserverclick = "SignUp_Server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use asp button

```
<asp:Button id="btnSignUp" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" onclientclick = "return SignUp_Client();" onclick = "SignUp_Server"/>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible with a html control?

Comment: I never tried it. Possibly you will have to try `$.ajax` for that

Answer (score 0):

Chage input type to "submit"

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSignUp" runat="server" value="Sign Up" onclick = "return SignUp_Client();" onserverclick = "SignUp_Server"/>
```

After changing type to submit it will call server side event also.

Hope this will help.